# What is the general strategy for passing an electrical cable (120V/15A) behind a drywall?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I'd like to set up a new receptacle 12 ft away from an existing (120V/60Hz/15A) receptacle in a garage.

I understand that one would drill a hole every so often, and that one should pass the electric cable by inserting one's hand/forearm in one and out of the other, or else one would use a fish cable to pass the electrical cable from one hole to the next.

But I'm unclear how big each hole should be, or the distance between them. I'm also unclear how the cable should pass through the studs.

What is the general strategy for passing an electrical cable (120V/15A) behind a drywall?

[image: receptacle in dry wall above concrete in garage]

Comment: You try to use the easiest path.  Usually with a wall, you go down or up.  Your case I would go up to the ceiling, one hole in the top plate, take the cable over and another hole in the top plate and down.

Comment: If you can't go up or down, you can use a long fishing drill bit designed for this.  They are quite flexible.

Comment: You can also consider surface wiring, e.g. Wiremold, so much quicker, easier, and cleaner.

Comment: @kreemoweet Can you add an answer explaining how you'd connect a Wiremold to the receptacle, and how to cut the 5-ft Wiremold sections to build a 12-ft long channel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like opening several 8x8 holes large enough to fit the drill into the hole, drilling blind two directions with the drill completely in the wall, then fishing string with a hook through the holes.

I would cut a 4" slot full length, easier to just fit head of drill through the slot, you can see both sides of stud. No string and hook fishing. I find patching one long slot is not harder to patch than several larger separate holes.

Comment: If the baseboard is tall enough, than can be pulled and the slotting done in that area, with no subsequent patching necessary.

Comment: Possibly, but the 2x4 bottom plate will likely push you above the baseboard. Also drilling holes close to the ends of load bearing studs isn't advised.